# Add an animated top bar to UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I have a UIWebView controller that loads a web page and I would like to add some kind of a bar at the top of the page with refresh and close buttons.
The bar should hide when the page loaded and should show again if the user taps the top part of the page.

Does anyone know how to approach it? Is there any simple way to do that?

UPDATE:
I think I wasn't clear enough with the question, so here are some clarifications:
     1. The applications is a standard application that one of the flows opens UIWebView that loads a web page
     2. What I'm looking for is a bar that will slide down on top of the web page (loaded in      UIWebView) and should help the user overcome a scenario where the web page is not loaded for some reason
     3. The bar should hold the back (just close the UIWebView) and refresh (reload UIWebView) operations.

Hope it helped.

Thanks,
Shimix

Comment: I'm actually working on something that uses something like this. I'll be glad to share. Get in touch with me if you want.

Comment: Thanks Moshe! Will contact you shortly...

Comment: You can find me in the [Meta Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/the-tavern-general), or my contact info is on my website, but you have to dig around there for it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing a library/project doing this, I don't think there is a simple way to do this.

I have already coded something similar to Safari mobile address bar, and from memory, it involved using private apis and/or playing with the *"not so private but use at your own risks"* `UIWebView` subviews hierarchy...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... I wonder why there is no simple way, as it seems like a common request (although it's still very hard to find a solution...).

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something like this right now and so far, here's what I've come up with. Some of this may be obvious, but important:

- Your address bar should be the left `navigationItem`.
- The search bar is the rign `navigationItem`.
- You should animate a cancel button in/out when beginning/ending editing in the URL box.
- Safari Mobile uses the `Prompt` property of the `navigationBar` to display webpage titles.
- To animate the widths of the search/URL bars, use `UIView` animation when the bar is selected.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to add a UIToolbar above the webview with UIBarButtonItems that call the webview's refresh, back, and forward methods. You can also add the webviewdelegate methods to your view controller to detect when the page has finished loading and hide/show the toolbar that way.

If you want the refresh and navigation controls to be displayed as part of the html content of the webview itself, that's a littler tricker, but not impossible. You can use the webview's shouldLoadRequest delegate method to detect that those buttons have been tapped, and then take the appropriate action within your viewcontroller. Hiding and showing the nav bar would have to be handled in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that placing the bar above the page will help me in this case. Also, the back button should actually just close the UIWebView and the refresh button should reload the UIWebView. What do you think?

Comment: If you use the UIWebViewDelegate methods, then you can intercept requests made in the webview. So, in the bar in your web content, make the back button image link with href="webview_go_back" or something like that, then in the webViewShouldStartRequest delegate method, check for "webview_go_back" in the request's url and you'll be able to tell when the user has tapped the back button in the webview. Then do whatever you want, close the webview, whatever. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes and I actually implemented the "back" button in the web page to point to special URL and handle it with the delegate method. But what happens if the web page itself didn't load at all? In that case the "back" button in the web page doesn't show... How can the user go back to the application?

Comment: there's a webview delegate method to detect when the page fails to load (didFailLoadWithError) that you can use to detect this and go back to the app.